# Dart how to create parallel operations for Bloc Events?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a little question. How can we create parallel tasks for bloc events? Let's suppose I have a object list and I'm trying to do something with each one of them. Currently I'm doing this

```
for (MyObject e in MyObjectList) {
   myBloc.add(DoSomething(e));
}
```

Is there a way to run this add line parallel and don't wait for previous operations? When I'm searching this I always faced with **"future wait"** but it's not for my use case. Is there a good approach for this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to pass all the objects to the BLoC and let the bloc decide whether it should be in parallel?

Comment: I think nothing will change. My goal is to reduce the waiting time by running processes that should not wait for each other at the same time. @nvoigt

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with the new bloc_concurrency package -> https://verygood.ventures/blog/how-to-use-bloc-with-streams-and-concurrency

From your example I see that the ask is to dispatch multiple events to your bloc at once (concurrently). You can glance through an example here that [explains](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-bloc-concurrency-simplified-6348ec4c2510#:%7E:text=Bloc%20Concurrency%20Solution&text=concurrent()%3A%20process%20events%20concurrently,at%20the%20same%20time%20concurrently.) this better

Comment: actually this answer isn't related with my question.